# Why is minSdkVersion too new?

Tags: android, android-11

Trying to test a sample app related to the new Bubbles api.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
```

**build.gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bubbles"
    minSdkVersion 'Q'
    targetSdkVersion 'android-R'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Here are my virtual devices. I'm running on `Pixel 3 API R`.

[image]

Shouldn't this be sufficient to run an API 30 app on this device? I'm not sure what the conflict is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
minSdkVersion 'Q'
targetSdkVersion 'android-R'
```

with:

```
minSdkVersion 'R'
targetSdkVersion 'R'
```

Q was the 2019 release, so that's not what you want for a `minSdkVersion`. And `android-R` shouldn't be recognized as a valid `targetSdkVersion` value — that syntax is only for `compileSdkVersion`.

(and, yes, this is all just a mess and has been for years...)

Comment: Thanks again. I need to find where to get this in the documentation.

Comment: @AndroidDev: https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk#update-build, though they do not show `minSdkVersion` there. IIRC, setting the `targetSdkVersion` to `R` forces a `minSdkVersion` of `R` automatically.

Comment: Thank you yet again!

Comment: @CommonsWare Are you sure about this? I decompiled an apk using apktool and it showed an `minSdkVersion` of `21` as it should be, but it still didn't install correctly.

Comment: @ThexXTURBOXx: "Are you sure about this?" -- am I sure about what? "but it still didn't install correctly" -- a pre-release `targetSdkVersion` seems to override what you literally have for `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @CommonsWare According to my observations, the `minSdkVersion` doesn't get overridden. As I said, apktool reports the right `minSdkVersion`, but the device still won't install it because of the error mentioned above.

Comment: @ThexXTURBOXx: It used to, in past years' versions of the build tools. Perhaps they elected to just bake it into the OS itself, ignoring your `minSdkVersion` if you have the pre-release `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: @CommonsWare This seems reasonable. That could explain some of my other observations as well. Thank you very much